# Se puede mandar las respuestas de un formulario a un div en la misma pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, formularios

**Si pongo un formulario como el siguiente**

```
<form action="ejemplo.php" method="get">
  <p>Nombre: <input name="nombre" size="40" type="text" /></p>

  <p>A&ntilde;o de nacimiento: <input min="1900" name="nacido" type="number" /></p>

  <p>Sexo: <input name="hm" type="radio" value="h" /> Hombre <input name="hm" type="radio" value="m" /> Mujer</p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> <input type="reset" value="Borrar" /></p>
</form>

<div><p>Que aparezca aquí la repuesta de nombre</p></div>
<div><p>Que aparezca aquí la respuesta de nacimiento</p></div>
<div><p>Que aparezca aquí la respuesta de sexo</p></div>
```

Como lo pongo anteriormente, quiero que la respuesta del formulario sea reflejada en las respuestas escritas en cada div diferente  ya sea usando jquery o javascript, o ¿qué metodo me recomendarían para hacer eso?

Comment: Es algo muy sencillo, de hecho es el comportamiento por defecto cuando no hay action en el tag del formulario. Considera utilizar ajax.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp en esta web no te costara encontrar un ejemplo de AJAX con PHP

Comment: puedes crear un evento que detecte cada letra que se escribe (jquery o javascript) y que lo pase al div pertinente

Comment: @AndresDominguezBravo sería mejor que sugirieras algo de documentación como MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si mal no entiendo, no necesitas hacer la acción `submit` sino mostrar la información introducida por el usuario en el bloque inferior...

Te dejo este ejemplo con `jQuery` en el que agrego un par de detalles a tu código original, como por ejemplo, agregar `id` a cada `input` y clases a cada `<p>` para tratar de que te quede claro el concepto, pero *puedes usar `id` también en los párrafos, siempre y cuando sean diferentes para cada uno*.

```js
$('#boton').click(function(){
  //Capturo el valor introducido por el usuario en el input con id nombre
  //y lo asigno al parrafo con clase nombre... igual para el año de nacimiento 
  $('.nombre').html('El nombre es: '+$('#nombre').val());
  $('.nacido').html('El año de nacimineto es: '+$('#nacido').val());
  //Los radio button tienen un comportamiento diferente para capturar el valor
  $('.sexo').html('El sexo es: '+$('input:radio[name=hm]:checked').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ejemplo.php" method="get">
  <p>Nombre: <input name="nombre" id="nombre" size="40" type="text" /></p>

  <p>Año de nacimiento: <input min="1900" name="nacido" id="nacido" type="number" /></p>

  <p>Sexo: <input name="hm" type="radio" value="h" /> Hombre <input name="hm" type="radio" value="m" /> Mujer</p>

  <p><input type="button" id="boton" value="Enviar" /> <input type="reset" value="Borrar" /></p>
</form>

<div><p class="nombre"></p></div>
<div><p class="nacido"></p></div>
<div><p class="sexo"></p></div>
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es que se vea reflejado sin necesidad de hacer click en el botón, puedes usar diferentes métodos de `jQuery`, como `keyup` por ejemplo...

```js
$('#nombre').keyup(function(){ 
  $('.nombre').html('El nombre es: '+$('#nombre').val());
});
$('#nacido').keyup(function(){ 
  $('.nacido').html('El año de nacimineto es: '+$('#nacido').val());
});
$('input:radio[name=hm]').click(function(){ 
  $('.sexo').html('El sexo es: '+$('input:radio[name=hm]:checked').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ejemplo.php" method="get">
  <p>Nombre: <input name="nombre" id="nombre" size="40" type="text" /></p>

  <p>Año de nacimiento: <input min="1900" name="nacido" id="nacido" type="number" /></p>

  <p>Sexo: <input name="hm" type="radio" value="h" /> Hombre <input name="hm" type="radio" value="m" /> Mujer</p>

  <p><input type="button" id="boton" value="Enviar" /> <input type="reset" value="Borrar" /></p>
</form>

    <div><p class="nombre"></p></div>
    <div><p class="nacido"></p></div>
    <div><p class="sexo"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Un formulario (una etiqueta `<form>`), cuando se le ejecuta la acción `submit`, enviará los datos de todos sus campos `input` a la dirección indicada en el atributo `action`. Para lo que quieres necesitas dos cosas: evitar que se envíen los datos (que haría que el navegador cargase otra página) y copiar los datos a otro sitio con Javascript.

La solución más sencilla es ignorar el parámetro "action" y luego copiar los datos con Javascript. Para ignorar el action, tenemos que decirle al formulario que no ejecute la acción predeterminada asociada al evento *submit*. Para eso se llama al método `preventDefault()` del evento:

```js
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

formulario.addEventListener('submit', copiarDatos);

function copiarDatos(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const nombre = document.querySelector('input[name=nombre]').value;
  const nacido = document.querySelector('input[name=nacido]').value;
  const inputsSexo = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=hm]'));
  const sexo = inputsSexo.find(input => input.checked).value;
  
  document.getElementById('nombre').innerHTML='Nombre: ' + nombre;
  document.getElementById('nacido').innerHTML=' Año de nacimiento' + nacido;
  document.getElementById('sexo').innerHTML= 'Sexo: '+ (sexo == 'h') ? 'Hombre' : 'Mujer';
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <p>Nombre: <input name="nombre" size="40" type="text" /></p>

  <p>A&ntilde;o de nacimiento: <input min="1900" name="nacido" type="number" /></p>

  <p>Sexo: <input name="hm" type="radio" value="h" /> Hombre <input name="hm" type="radio" value="m" /> Mujer</p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> <input type="reset" value="Borrar" /></p>
</form>

<div ><p id="nombre">Que aparezca aquí la repuesta de nombre</p></div>
<div><p id="nacido">Que aparezca aquí la respuesta de nacimiento</p></div>
<div><p id="sexo">Que aparezca aquí la respuesta de sexo</p></div>
```